# Convert a entryGetText into Int gtk2hs

Tags: haskell, io, gtk2hs

I'm trying to convert a entryText into a string, so I can use it for other functions.

```
`unsafePerformIO (entryGetText txtMagn)`
```

While trying to compile this code, I get the error message:

```
`Couldn't match type ‘IO a0 -> a0’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: IO a0 -> a0
    Probable cause: ‘unsafePerformIO’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘unsafePerformIO’`
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you wrote

```
putStrLn unsafePerformIO (entryGetText txtMagn)
```

Here you pass `unsafePerformIO` to `putStrLn` as a parameter. You actually meant:

```
putStrLn (unsafePerformIO (entryGetText txtMagn))
```

Now to the `unsafePerformIO`. As its name suggests, it is **unsafe**, so you'd better have a clear idea what are you trying to accomplish. To safely pull out your value out of the `IO` and use it later:

```
text <- entryGetText txtMagn
putStrLn text
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value, you have to use the read function:

```
val <- getLine
someFunctionWhichNeedsTheValue (read val ::Float)
```